# sdbus++ can't call functions

Tags: c++, linux, dbus

I am trying to make a media controller,  I want to connect to an existing bus of type "MediaPlayer2" and run "Next" to get to the next song. When I run my code I get this error

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
  what():  vector::_M_range_check: __n (which is 0) >= this->size() (which is 0)
```

This is my code

```
void InitializeConnection()
{
    sd_bus* bus;
    sd_bus_error error;

    //Check if player is null to assign the first player
    sdbus::IConnection& connection = *sdbus::createConnection();
    if(currentPlayerName.empty()){
        player = sdbus::createProxy(
            "org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.spotifyd.instance687", 
            "/org/mpris/MediaPlayer2/spotifyd/instance687"
        ); 
        currentPlayerName = playerNames.at(0);
    }

    try{
        player->callMethod("Next");
    }catch(const sdbus::Error& e){
       cerr << "Got concatenate error " << e.getName() << " with message " << e.getMessage() << std::endl;   
    }
}
```

I expected to connect and play the next song or at least exit the function or maybe enter the catch block